# Question about Keras implementation of ADAM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mathematical-optimization

I have a question regarding [this line](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/b3ffea6602dbbb481e82312baa24fe657de83e11/keras/optimizers/adam.py#L174) in the Keras implementation of Adam:

> alpha = lr * tf.sqrt(1 - beta_2_power) / (1 - beta_1_power)

From the algorithm [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/234686/243601), is this step doing the bias correction? If so, it seems like they are also implicitly scaling `epsilon` by a `(1 - beta_2_power)^0.5` factor, which is not in the original algorithm? I understand practically this doesn't matter since epsilon is just there to avoid a divide by zero, but just wanted to make sure I understood this correctly.